# Possible memory leak in android. Might be using the wrong cleanup method, or missing something

Tags: android

I have a memory leak. Here's the code

```
package fourguys.testing.IntentTest;

import android.app.Activity; import android.media.MediaPlayer; import android.os.Bundle; import android.os.Handler; import android.os.Message; import android.media.MediaPlayer; import android.media.AudioManager; import android.content.Context;

public class CanvasDrawingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int FIRE = 0;
    private int initVolume = 0;
    private Handler handler;
    private MyCanvas v;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private AudioManager am;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // this method gets the current volume setting for music
        initVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);

        makeHandler();
        v =new MyCanvas(this);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(FIRE);
        }}).start();
        setContentView(v);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
    private void makeHandler()
    {
        handler  = new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch(msg.what)
                {
                    case FIRE:
                    {
                        v.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        };
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.stop();
    }
    protected void onFinish() {
        mp.stop();
    }

}
```

and this:

```
package fourguys.testing.IntentTest;

import android.app.Activity; import android.content.Intent; import android.media.MediaPlayer; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.view.WindowManager;

public class IntentTest extends Activity { /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //reciever intentReceiver = new reciever();

        // IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.app.REC");

        //registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
        Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.endButton);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(IntentTest.this,CanvasDrawingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
    // the onPause method get called when the app is either being hidden or being closed so this the place where we would want to clean anything up like stoping the media player.
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

I run the app and it gets wonky on exit. It locks the handset and causes the battery to run hot. I need to pull the battery physically to reboot. Any thoughts as to why that might be? It runs fantastically on the emulator. Should I be using onFinish instead, or am I not cleaning something up and I'm missing it?

Comment: The code viewer is acting weird, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It is this part of your code:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(FIRE);
        }}).start();
```

You're doing three obvious things wrong here. 1) You're not killing it and/or pausing it in `Activity#onPause`. 2) You're not calling [`setDaemon(true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29); this will cause the process to continue and not die while this thread is running. 3) you're using a hot loop, i.e., you're not calling `Thread#sleep()` or some other type of equivalent method there to pause and stop fully using the cpu.

Comment: OK, so I'm leaving the door open basically. I must confessmy ignorance as a newer dev. Do you have a reference on those 3 things you referenced? I'm not sure how I'd kill that activity or clean it up. I honestly did expect this issue to stem from that area though, so my gut reaction was that this was the issue.

Comment: ok let me take a stab at what I'm thinking your  suggestions could mean:

Comment: 1) I need to do like a Thread.stop(); in the onPause or onFinish? 2) I'm unfamiliar with this. So am I making Thread.setDaemon(true) before the thread begins to run? Is that the process? 3) I'm confused as to whether I should use sleep() or stop(). I want to kill the thread, but how do I impliment that? Do I use sleep in my onPause? That seems to need an interval, which would be the entire time it's paused. Some clarification of whether I understand these concepts correctly would be immensely appreciated. Thanks so much!